# Espresso Webview select hidden element

Tags: android, webview, android-testing, android-espresso

How do you find a hidden element inside an Android Webview using espresso? This is what I tried:

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.CSS_SELECTOR, "#clsp:hidden"));
```

That produces the following stacktrace.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in
>   evaluationEvaluation: status: 13 value: {message=An invalid or illegal
>   selector was specified} hasMessage: true message: An invalid or
>   illegal selector was specified at
>   android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction$ExceptionPropagator.(Web.java:323)
>   at
>   android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.doEval(Web.java:292)
>   at
>   android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.withElement(Web.java:208)
>   at
>   com.middlestump.MainActivityInstrumentationTest.createAlert(MainActivityInstrumentationTest.java:89)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)

The MainActivityInstrumentationTest.java:89 bit is the line of code I have given.

Also tried:

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.CSS_SELECTOR, "#clsp")).check(isDisplayed());
```

But there is a type mismatch between `WebAssertion` and `ViewAssertion`

Comment: hi. i am facing similar issue. can you please help how you resolved this crash.?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278457/expresso-ui-test-fail-on-executing-webkeys-command-this-happening-on-android-ve

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar issue. Does anybody found out the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Swipe webview and find the hidden element:

```
onView(withId(R.id.webView)).perform(ViewActions.swipeUp());
```